# How to read xml file from local drive on click of button without using browse option?

Tags: apex, xml

I want to get the string value of an xml file which is stored in a predefined location in my local system(D:\Product Files).
The problem is I don't want to use the browse option & want to read & parse the xml file internally on click of button - Process File.
PS:-I already have the parse logic in place but not able to read the file from local system.

Comment: If its a file accessible to you in your own pc or server, you can come up with webservice which reads the file, parses it and returns the value. then you can call the webservice from the custom button.

Comment: I'm using the below code   `public void getFile() { Http h = new Http(); HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); req.setEndpoint('file:///D:/Product Files/ProductXML.xml'); req.setMethod('GET'); HttpResponse res = h.send(req); Dom.Document doc = res.getBodyDocument(); System.debug('doc.toXmlString()++++++++++++++ '+doc.toXmlString() ); }`    But getting error - Unauthorized endpoint = file:///D:/Product Files/ProductXML.xml

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is impossible to do without having to upload the file first. Imagine the risk if that was possible - you can write a code that will look into specific locations for specific files and you could read other users' confidential documents for an example.

The closest thing you can do is to access a sandboxed FileSystem using HTML5 - [read more](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/).

Answer (score 0):

I could do the same using Document tab in salesforce.
I placed my file in a folder in Document object & then read & parsed the same file in my controller which is called on click of a button.